# Is there any way to add company info to Alexa service and use it without invocation name?

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

do you know maybe how to add info about our company to Alexa voice service?
Cause now I have a skill with lambda and so on, and to ask about company I have to install the skill on Alexa device, then start the skill and the ask what I want...

But when I ask "Alexa, what is a dog". I've got an answer which was explained what is it. So how to do the same skill for name of company like "Alexa what is a company_name?", and she will explain what I will give her (probably in lambda).

Please give me some advice about how to search it because now I feel like I would search the whole internet and don't know what else to enter to find the answer...

Answer (score 0):

Probably the only way to share an answer without installing a custom skill is by means of Alexa Answers (https://alexaanswers.amazon.com/about), but you can't still insert the question there.

Comment: Thank you for your help but this still doesn't solve my problem.